# Trying to generate a pdf table that will be stored on s3 and immediately retreived as an automated email attachment

Tags: java, spring-mvc, amazon-s3, itext, aws-sdk

Currently, my code is written to generate a pdf file containing a flight itinerary to a local drive. The system will automatically send an email with the itinerary attached(which is retrieved from that same local path). I want to be able to store and retrieve these itinerary's from my AWS S3 bucket. My application is written in Java using Spring-boot/MVC/Maven. I can't seem to figure this one out. I just graduated from college with a BSIT in software development. I'm really striving to strengthen my skill set but it looks like I'm going to need help solving this one.

Service Layer-

package com.louis.mywebapplication.service;

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.louis.mywebapplication.dto.ReservationRequest;
import com.louis.mywebapplication.entities.Flight;
import com.louis.mywebapplication.entities.Passenger;
import com.louis.mywebapplication.entities.Reservation;
import com.louis.mywebapplication.repos.FlightRepository;
import com.louis.mywebapplication.repos.PassengerRepository;
import com.louis.mywebapplication.repos.ReservationRepository;
import com.louis.mywebapplication.util.EmailUtil;
import com.louis.mywebapplication.util.PDFGenerator;


@Service
public class ReservationServiceImpl implements ReservationService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =                                                 LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReservationServiceImpl.class);

    @Value("${com.louis.webapplication.itinerary.dirpath}")
    String ITINERARY_DIR;

    @Autowired
    FlightRepository flightRepository;

    @Autowired
    PassengerRepository passengerRepository;

    @Autowired
    ReservationRepository reservationRepository;

    @Autowired
    PDFGenerator pdfGenerator;

    @Autowired
    EmailUtil emailUtil;

    @Override
    public Reservation bookFlight(ReservationRequest request) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside bookFlight()");
        //Make Payment

        Long flightId = request.getFlightId();
    LOGGER.info("Fetching flight for flight id:"+flightId);
        Flight flight = flightRepository.findById(flightId).get();
        Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
        passenger.setFirstName(request.getPassengerFirstName());
        passenger.setLastName(request.getPassengerLastName());
        passenger.setPhone(request.getPassengerPhone());
        passenger.setEmail(request.getPassengerEmail());
    LOGGER.info("Saving the passenger: "+passenger);
        Passenger savedPassenger = passengerRepository.save(passenger); 
        Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
        reservation.setFlight(flight);
        reservation.setPassenger(savedPassenger);
        reservation.setCheckedIn(false);
    LOGGER.info("Saving the reservation:"+reservation);
        Reservation savedReservation reservationRepository.save(reservation);
        String filePath = ITINERARY_DIR+savedReservation.getId()+".pdf";
    LOGGER.info("Generation the ininerary");
        pdfGenerator.generateItinerary(savedReservation, filePath);
    LOGGER.info("Emailing the ininerary");
        emailUtil.sendItinerary(passenger.getEmail(), filePath);
        return savedReservation;
    }

}
```

---

Utility Layer-

```
package com.louis.mywebapplication.util;

import java.io.File;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EmailUtil {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class);

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender sender;

    @Value("${com.louis.mywebapplicationn.itinerary.email.subject}")
    private String EMAIL_SUBJECT;

    @Value("${com.louis.mywebapplicationn.itinerary.email.body}")
    private String EMAIL_BODY;

    public void sendItinerary(String toAddress, String filePath) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside sendItinerary()");
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();

        try {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            messageHelper.setTo(toAddress);
            messageHelper.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT);
            messageHelper.setText(EMAIL_BODY);

            messageHelper.addAttachment("Itinerary", new File(filePath));
            sender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.louis.mywebapplication.util;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.louis.mywebapplication.entities.Reservation;

@Component
public class PDFGenerator {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PDFGenerator.class);
    //
    public void generateItinerary(Reservation reservation, String filePath) {
        LOGGER.info("generateItinerary()");
        Document document = new Document();

        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            document.open();
            document.add(generateTable(reservation));
            document.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //
    private PdfPTable generateTable(Reservation reservation) {

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPCell cell;

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Flight Itinerary"));
        cell.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Flight Details"));
        cell.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(cell);

        table.addCell("Airlines");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getOperatingAirlines());

        table.addCell("Departure City");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getDepartureCity());

        table.addCell("Arrival City");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getArrivalCity());

        table.addCell("Flight Number");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getFlightNumber());

        table.addCell("Departure Date");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getDateOfDeparture().toString());

        table.addCell("Departure Time");
        table.addCell(reservation.getFlight().getEstimatedDepartureTime().toString());

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Passengerr Details"));
        cell.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(cell);

        table.addCell("First Name");
        table.addCell(reservation.getPassenger().getFirstName());

        table.addCell("Last Name");
        table.addCell(reservation.getPassenger().getLastName());

        table.addCell("Email");
        table.addCell(reservation.getPassenger().getEmail());

        table.addCell("Phone");
        table.addCell(reservation.getPassenger().getPhone());

        return table;
    }

}
```

Comment: Some clarifying questions before I can answer.  Are you saying that you do not want the pdf to live on local disk, even temporarily, or that after your program is done running you would like it to store the file on s3?  Lastly, are you saying you want to send an email with a link to the file stored on s3 instead of embedded in the email as an attachment?

Comment: Hi Ivoelk, thanks for responding. This application will be running on ElasticBean Stalk. I'm thinking it would be fine to temporarily store these files locally? Essentially, the use-case is after the user completes the flight reservation form, an email will be sent to the user containing the attached pdf file. I figured that storing these pdf files to s3 would be a little more convenient. I'm also open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Spring Content](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content).  This project allows you to manage content (i.e. your generated PDFs) and associate it with your Spring Data Entities.  It also provides the same programming model as Spring Data, just for files and other binary content.

For example, assuming you are using Spring Data REST (and Spring Boot), you could add an SDR event handler that, upon creation of a new Reservation (via the SDR endpoint), triggers the generation of your PDF and then uses Spring Content to store the PFD in S3 and associate it with the reservation.

The project is easy to add to your project as follows:

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-s3-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

> S3Configuration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableS3Stores
public class S3Configuration {
    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 client() {
        return ...your client here...
    }

}
```

> Reservation.java

```
@Entity
public class Reservation {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   ...other existing fields...

   /////////////
   //
   // Add Spring Content annotations to allow content to be associated 

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;

   @MimeType
   private String mimeType = "";

   ...
}
```

> ReservationPDFContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="reservationPdfs")
public interface ReservationPDFContentStore extends ContentStore<Reservation, String> {
}
```

> ReservationEventHandler.java

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(Reservation.class) 
public class ReservationEventHandler {

  @Autowired
  private PDFGenerator;

  @Autowired
  private ReservationPDFContentStore store;


  @HandleAfterCreate
  public void handleReservationAfterCreate(Reservation reservation){
    // generate your PDF and associate the content with your reservation
    String filePath = ...
    pdfGenerator.generateItinerary(savedReservation, filePath);
    InputStream pfdIn = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    store.setContent(reservation, pdfIn);

    // don't forget to close pdfIn!
  }
}
```

At a high-level this would be all you need to do.

How this actually works is very much like Spring Data.  When your application starts Spring Content will see the `spring-content-s3-boot-starter` dependencies and know that you want to store content in S3.  It will inject a S3-based implementation of the `ReservationPDFContentStore` interface, using the client @Bean setup in the config as its connection.  It will also see the `spring-content-rest-boot-starter` and will inject REST endpoints that talk to the content store interface.

So, for example:

`curl -X POST /reservations/`
(with an appropriate application/hal+json payload)

will create a new reservation in your system and trigger the event handler that will generate the PDF, store it in S3 and associate it with the newly created reservation.

`curl /reservationPdfs/{reservationId}`

will fetch the PDF when you need it.

The advantage of both Spring Data and Content is that other than the PDF generator you don't have to write any boilerplate controller or service code.  Given a couple of interfaces (extending `CrudRepository` and `ContentStore`) Spring is able to inject it all for you.

You can find more Spring Content examples [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).

HTH

Comment: Two things on this solution, one is if you are using spring data you should use spring data.  Do not use spring data to integrate with a given database for some parts of your application and other persistence frameworks or even hard-coded queries for others.  Second make sure you still have a good methodology for storing the file locally and then deleting as you do not want to write the output stream straight to s3 as you will then have to download it to email, doubling up on your s3 charges.

Comment: Actually, you raise a good point that I was going to mention and decided not to but since you raise it here.  Personally, I would look to refactor the pdf generator to return a stream that can be fed straight into the setContent method.  That way, no need to local files and clean-up code.

Comment: That won't work because he needs to both save the file to s3 and email it to the user.  Since you can't stream the file to two places at once you only have two good options.  One, write the file locally to disk then stream to both email and s3 from there, or two hold the file entirely in memory then write it to the email and s3 from memory.  The last thing you want to do is write to s3 then read from it to send the email, coding with Amazon services is all about cost optimization you can get into a very bad place very quickly if your not careful.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is mostly fine for generating the files and emailing. I would recommend writing the files to a temp folder (under /usr/local if this in Linux under Users/your user if windows) then delete the file after it has been emailed.  The only reason to store them on s3 would be if you need to retrieve them later via your application.  If so then the best way to do this is to create a table in your database to store the metadata you will use to search for the file such as (user Id, file name, date, s3 bucket, s3key, ...)  You can then use the s3 java API to write the file to s3 (prior to deleting it from tmp).  Examples of the s3 java API can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3.html.
here is a basic example of putting a file on s3:

```
 AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
 AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
        .build();
s3client.putObject(bucket, key, file);
```

Comment: Ivoelk, where could I temporarily store the pdf files while running the application on the ElasticBean Stalk server? That's my primary issue. My entire project runs fine on my PC. I need a new file path to store these files while it's running live on the Amazon server.

Comment: Assuming your amazon servers are running a linux ami, then best practice would be to make a directory to put the files into called tmp.  The best place to put this would be under /usr/local/ but some people put them in other places.  Since elastic beanstalk will regularly recreate instances for your java code will need to check if the directory exists and make if not.  Make sure you delete the files when you are done with them though as you do not want to incur lots of Elastic Block Store charges on your EC instances.